# Set a value in a class with reflection, with the Class, Field and value as parameters in a method

Tags: java, reflection

I have this method that is supposed to set a field in the given class to the specified value:

```
public void setValue(Class<?> instance, String fieldName, Object value) {
    try {
        Field field = instance.getDeclaredField(fieldName);

        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(instance, value);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        if (instance.getSuperclass() != null) {
            setValue(instance.getSuperclass(), fieldName, value);
        } else {
            try {
                throw new NoSuchFieldException("Could not find field " + fieldName + " in any class.");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException exx) {
        exx.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, it gives this error when I try to set any field:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set float field net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.Packet43SetExperience.a to java.lang.Class
```

I have tried using an Object(instead of an Class) but it never finds the field that I need, it only finds the fields that the Object class has. 
I also tried using generics, but the same thing happened.

Comment: Minecraft mod to let you add xp... sounds kind of like cheating xD.

Comment: I am using this to use the xp bar as a "recharging" bar for a spell plugin, when the bar is full it means the spell can be cast again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the actual instance of the object to [pass in to the `set` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29), not the `Class` object itself.  Add a parameter to your method to take the actual instance:

```
public void setValue(Class<?> clazz, Object instance, String fieldName, Object value) {
```

I renamed the `Class<?>` parameter `clazz` for clarity, so it would need to be changed elsewhere:

```
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
```

And pass the actual instance to `set`:

```
field.set(instance, value);
```